# vue-meta refusing to render server-side on nuxt app

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-meta

I have `{src: '~/plugins/vue-meta.js', ssr: true},` in `nuxt.config.js`

in `index.vue`:

```
  async asyncData({ params, store }) {
    await store.dispatch("articles/getArticle", params.slug);
    return {
      article: store.getters["articles/getArticle"]
    };
  },
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: this.article.title,
      meta: [
        {
          vmid: "description",
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content: this.article.meta_tag_content
        },
        {
          property: "og:title",
          hid: "og-title",
          vmid: "og-title",
          content: this.article.title
        },
        {
          property: "og:description",
          hid: "og-description",
          vmid: "og-description",
          content: this.article.meta_tag_content
        },
        {
          property: "og:image",
          hid: "og-image",
          vmid: "og-image",
          content: this.article.small_image_url
        },
        {
          property: "og:type",
          hid: "og-type",
          vmid: "og-type",
          content: "article"
        },
        {
          property: "og:url",
          hid: "og-url",
          vmid: "og-url",
          content: location.origin
        },
        {
          name: "twitter:card",
          hid: "twitter-card",
          vmid: "twitter-card",
          content: this.article.meta_tag_content
        }
      ]
    };
  },
```

but none of this renders server-side - it only renders client-side, which means Facebook will not read the OG meta elements.

Is there something else that needs to be set for Nuxt to render this server-side?

The mode is set to "universal" in nuxt.config.js. It doesn't matter whether I use generate, run dev or run start, it's the same result in all of them.

Comment: hmm, I just tested your descriptions using a fresh nuxtjs created project, and it works for me? What I did: create '~/plugins/vue-meta.js', add the code specified in the "Installation" section of vue-meta, `yarn add vue-meta`, add the plugin to `nuxt.config.js` as you said and then create a simple index.vue with static `data()` function and your `metaInfo()`. Then it did render the meta info server side successfully.

Comment: But see my answer as well, you shouldn't even need to add `vue-meta` manually as its already part of nuxt by default.

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt.js already includes `vue-meta` by default. However, you need to use `head()` instead of `metaInfo()`.

From the [vue-meta docs](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/guide/metainfo.html):

> **Note**
>
> Altough we talk about the `metaInfo` variable on this page, please note that the `keyName` is configurable and could be different in your case. E.g. Nuxt.js uses `head` as `keyName`

So replace `metaInfo` by `head` and remove the `{src: '~/plugins/vue-meta.js', ssr: true}` (as it is already included) then it should work (I tested this on a fresh project).

Comment: Thanks - I tried doing this, and now it doesn't render the meta at all. There's obviously something wrong somewhere else, but I inherited this project and have no idea how to find the problem...

Comment: OK I got a probable solution from elsewhere - the entire <nuxt> element is wrapped in <no-ssr>. Why, I have no idea. I also have no idea why `head` won't work but `metaInfo` does - even if I remove the vue-meta plugin from nuxt.config.js - maybe if I remove <no-ssr> that will also fix that issue, or something else weird might be causing it! thanks for looking into this